# GeoGraphics Manipulation

Tags: geography, geographics

So far this is what i have:

```
   countries = EntityList[EntityClass["Country", "EuropeSovereign"]];
   GeoGraphics[countries, ImageSize -> 500, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"]
```

I want to be able to do these things:

1. add country border line
2. change the color scheme for "ReliefMap" - to a gray level scheme? is that possible?
3. I have a list of lat/long data that I'd like to plot on the map and be able to label them with numbers. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scheme of the `Relief` plot can be set using the `ColorFunction` option. The country border can be shown using `Polygon` and the location can be labeled using `GeoMarker`. Here is an example

```
countries = EntityList[EntityClass["Country", "EuropeSovereign"]];
loc = EntityValue[EntityValue[countries, "CapitalCity"], "Position"];

GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Red], Polygon /@ countries, 
  Table[GeoMarker[loc[[n]], Style[n, Green]], {n, 1, Length@loc}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap", ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this is great. I have a question though about formatting loc. Say i want to plot one location e.g. Paris lat: 48.864716;long: 2.349014. How should i define loc?

Comment: @user147813 You can use `GeoPosition[{48.864716,2.349014}]` to do that. You may want to have a look at the documentation page of `GeoPosition`, it has many examples.

Comment: When asking for a property of a list of entities, it is faster to use a single EntityValue call, as in loc = EntityValue[countries, "CapitalCity"], rather than using Map. Note also that you do not need to get the "Position" of each city in advance in this particular case, because the Geo functions can obtain the position themselves (and will do it minimizing the number of EntityValue calls).

Comment: @jose Thanks! I have edited the post to reflect that. I didn't know EntityValue is listable. The "Position" is added in purpose, so that the `GeoPosition` structure would be clear for the OP to change to other lat and long values.